# ¿Cómo llamar un método de mi Web Api directamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Tengo un controlador en mi Web Api llamado ConfigController  y dentro un método llamado Index

Si  escribo en el navegador  ***http://localhost:5001/api/Config/Index***  me funciona perfecto,

Pero yo necesito llamarlo de la siguiente forma: ***http://localhost:5001/Index***

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Mi código:

```
  public class ConfigController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAppAggregateServices appAggregateServices;

    public ConfigController(IAppAggregateServices appAggregateServices)
    {
        this.appAggregateServices = appAggregateServices;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index()
    {
        string responseString = @"HOLA MUNDO ";
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StringContent(responseString);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente le agrega la decoración Route al método para cambiarle la ruta:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("Index")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Index()
        {
            string responseString = @"HOLA MUNDO ";
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent(responseString);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Richard Víquez Pérez     No funciona

Comment: Es .NET Framework o .NET Core???

Comment: Es un proyecto .Net Framework

Comment: Yo lo probé con net framework 4.6 como proyecto web api y funcionó!!!!!! Quizás sea por el IAppAggregateServices . Yo lo probé sin esa parte del código puede ser que afecte en algo